# Why codespaces add a extra port in the address?

Tags: spring-boot, codespaces

I am using Codespaces and I would like to know why if I run an Spring Boot Web application, running on port 8080, if I click in the link when I redirect port the address add an extra ":8080"

https://codespaces-name-8080.app.github.dev:8080/home

But it should be:

https://codespaces-name-8080.app.github.dev/home

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This address: `https://blog.cloudflare.com/super-bot-fight-mode/` is going to the default HTTPS port, which is port `443`. You said your Spring Boot app is running on port `8080`. Port `8080` is not the default HTTPS port, so the port has to be specified in the URL: `https://codespaces-name-8080.app.github.dev:8080/home`

Comment: It worked in that way. Many thanks